# List installed packages in channel

Tags: php, package, pear, channel

With PHP's PEAR, how can I check whether package `foo` in channel `bar` is already installed?  (Assuming that the channel `bar` is available, and has already been "discovered".)  Something like `pear list` that displays installed packages in channel `bar` only would be ideal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
pear list -c bar
```

Comment: Use `pear list -a` to list installed packages in *all* channels.